# absolute image covers other div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi there I am making a slide show using jquery in html and css. I found that I need to position the image of slide show to absolute and keep the div relative. but the problem is that once I set the image position as absolute other objects like the footer div and all gets hidden underneath the image. In other words the image positioned as absolute no longer remains inside div. how could I solve the problem please help. And of course all my objects are scalable so I cannot have a fixed size for anything. Thank you.

This is my code:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="slideshow"> <img src="images/Banners/bg_top_img2.jpg" class="slide"> <img src="images/Banners/bg_top_img3.jpg" class="slide"> <img src="images/Banners/bg_top_img4.jpg" class="slide"> </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div> THis is the footer </div </td>
</tr>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.slideshow{
position: relative:
width:100%;
background-color:#FF0;
float: left;    
}
.slide{
width:100%;
position: absolute;
display: block;

}
.slideshow > div{
position: absolute;
padding:2px;
width:100%;
height: auto;
bottom:2px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a screenshot or some code?

Comment: work with z-index, have your elements take a greater z-index from the image.

Comment: I have tried setting the z-index but thing is the div holding the image does not scale with the image. image comes out of the div with its own size and the dive followed after this div gets hidden or in other words you can say the height of the div holding the image does not change and the other rolls to top. there by making my div hidden below image. If any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @balida85, please do not ignore the first comment otherwise this question would be closed. Please provide the code you have by updating your question. You need to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this are  my html and css code:

Comment: <tr>
    <td >
    <div class="slideshow">
    <img src="images/Banners/bg_top_img2.jpg" class="slide">
    <img src="images/Banners/bg_top_img3.jpg" class="slide">
    <img src="images/Banners/bg_top_img4.jpg" class="slide">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>
 <div>
 THis is the footer
 </div
 </td>
    </tr>

Comment: Please update your question with the whole relevant code to replicate your problem, more exactly add the code that shows the problem you have, in your question, not in a comment. I've added the code you posted in the comment into your question above, but that is not enough for us to know the issue. Also you don't close a `div` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem why your footer hides behind the img is the "position: absolute"..
you could solve this by giving ur footer something like "top: 200px" (we cant see how big ur imgs are).

EDIT:
try to work with percent values like= top: 10%

or
try media querys like

```
@media only Screen and (max-width: xxxpx){
  .cssclass{
    top:100px;
 }
}
```

Comment: That's true Degcube.. but setting the top to 200px for footer will solve the problem only when the browser is maximized as when you resize the browser you will see the exact 200px gap in between the image and the footer, any other solution please feel free.

Comment: i guess there are no "better" solutions for absolute images, you could work with media querys like i edited in my answere or top: x%...

Comment: Thanks bro but I am looking for the correct answer for it as it has given me a pain in my ass from last 15days. thanks anyway.